# Install numpy for Python3 command not found error

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, redhat

Under `/numpy` folder

```
$ sudo python3 setup.py install
sudo：python3：command not found
```

Or try

```
$ sudo python3 distribute_setup.py
sudo：python3：command not found


$ python3
Python 3.2.2 (default, Sep 12 2013, 01:58:11) 
[GCC 4.6.3 20120306 (Red Hat 4.6.3-2)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

`which python3` says

```
$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

Update:

```
$ sudo which python3
which: no python3 in (/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin)
$ sudo echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/aws/bin:/home/xxxx/bin
```

Update2:

```
$ sudo sh -c 'echo $PATH'
/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

I have rhel/redhat and successfully installed python3.2.2 by downloading the package. Those threads about apt-get don't work for this version. Does anyone has an idea?

Comment: Does redhat change the search path (`$PATH`) when using `sudo`?  What do `sudo which python3` and `sudo echo $PATH` say?

Comment: The result of `sudo which python3` shows the problem.  When you use `sudo`, `/usr/local/bin` is not in $PATH.  I think `sudo echo $PATH` didn't do what I wanted; instead, check `sudo sh -c 'echo $PATH'`.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I already reinstalled. I don't know what's wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: You could try giving the full path to the `python3` command: `sudo /usr/local/bin/python3 setup.py install`.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Problem solved, it's amazing. Thanks a lot! I just curious why this happens. Where could I add a line and point to this path?

Comment: You'd have to ask a `sudo` and/or `redhat` expert for advice on changing the default search path for sudo.  But now that you are aware of this behavior, I don't think you have to change anything.  For the benefit of others, I'll summarize the comments here in an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `sudo` in redhat, `/usr/local/bin` is not included in the search path.  To run `python3` with `sudo`, give the full path to the executable:

```
$ sudo /usr/local/bin/python3 setup.py install
```

Answer (score 1):

Another rude solution is to copy symbolic link of `python3` and `pip3` from `/usr/local/bin` to `/usr/bin` :

```
$ sudo cp /usr/local/bin/python3 /usr/bin
$ sudo cp /usr/local/bin/pip3 /usr/bin
```